# Как сравнить две даты в контроллере?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, form, datetime

**Ввод данных (Views)**

```
@model WebLab11.Models.Information

@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Выбор сотрудника по окладу</title>
</head>
<body>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("getWorkersByOklad", "Default", FormMethod.Post))
    {//  @Html.DropDownList("IdJournal", null, new { @class = "form-control input-group-lg" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.basic_oklad, "Оклад", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.basic_oklad, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.size_salary, "Ставка", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.size_salary, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date_adop, "Дата принятия",  new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_adop,  "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Запрос 1" />


        </div>


    }
</body>
</html>
```

**Конроллер**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getWorkersByOklad(Information info)
        {
            WebEntities db = new WebEntities();


            var result = from ot in db.Information
                         join v in db.Workers on ot.id_worker equals v.id
                         join c in db.Positions on ot.id_pos equals c.id
                         where c.oklad == info.basic_oklad + info.size_salary
                         where ot.date_adop == Convert.ToDateTime("15.01.1998")
                         select new QueryFirstModel
                         {
                             Name = v.name,
                             Profession = c.name_pos
                         };

            return View("QuerySecondToTable", result);
        }
```

**Вывод результата**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebLab11.Models.QueryFirstModel>


@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    var data = ViewBag.Message;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Оклад</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">@Html.Label("Имя")</th>
                <th scope="col"> @Html.Label("Профессия")</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profession)</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Ошибка**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить данную ошибку ?

Comment: а если вместо `where ot.date_adop == Convert.ToDateTime("15.01.1998")` написать `where ot.date_adop == DateTime.Parse("15.01.1998")`

Comment: можете попробовать вынести выражение `Convert.ToDateTime("15.01.1998")` в отдельную переменную и уже её сравнивать в запросе

Comment: `return View("QuerySecondToTable", result);` ==> `return View("QuerySecondToTable", result.ToArray());`